# Rsync without password file without ssh

Tags: linux, windows, rsync

I would like to establish rsync between Windows 7 and linux server for file transfer. I am trying to make this as simple as possible. As topic, is there any way to use rsync without password file and ssh? I was searching for few days but only found solution with either password-file or ssh.

I am using:

### **Client Env**

- Windows 7
- cwRsync 5.5.0

### **Server Env**

- Linux Redhat 6.3 Santiago
- rsync 3.1.1

Comment: After several days, should should've come upon this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955707/rsync-with-ssh-remote-backup.  Perhaps you haven't copied your id_rsa.pub to the remote box?  Try editing your answer to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use rsync without using SSH at all, then you can do it using an rsync server.

It requires installing rsyncd on the Linux server, and setting up and configuring an always-running service, but there's a tutorial [here](https://everythinglinux.org/rsync/) (from 1999!) that says how to do it.

You can set it up to allow access without a username and password, but *only do that within a trusted network!* Note that, even with a password, there won't be any encryption, so use with caution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used host.allow by allowing ip address, but seems this is wrapper for address and action filtering moreover, this works on top of credential. After ip allowed it still request credential for the next move. Seems communication between 2 linux devices, authentication is a must.

Answer (score 0):

**on the source system:**

```
vim /etc/rsyncd.conf
```

then add your path

```
[your_path_name]
   path = /any_directory/your_path_name
   comment = My fast rsync server
   read only = yes
   list = yes
```

start the rsync server

```
sudo systemctl start rsync
```

**and on the destination server:**

```
 rsync -r rsync://X.X.X.X:/your_path_name ./my_directory/ --progress
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/etc/rsyncd.conf` instead of `/etc/rsync.conf`?

Comment: @mark Yes, I've edited my answer based on your comment.